# Hi All, I am facing some Mapping Exception. I know it's because of different fields in class, please suggest some ways to overcome it

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, dozer

This is my UserDTO class which I am using to store values coming from UI.

```
public class UserDTO {
 private String emailId;
 private String password;
 private String role;
 // getters and setters
}
```

And this is the Entity class which deals with the database(i am using hibernate).

```
public class UserEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "EmailId")
  private String emailId;

  @Column(name = "Password")
  private String password;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
  RoleEntity role;
  // getters and setters
}
```

And following is the RoleEntitity Class which is having a string role field.

```
public class RoleEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "role_id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "role")
  private String role;
  // getters and setters
}
```

I am getting user values from UI in request body.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces= {"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(adminService.createUser(userDTO), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Here, I want to map the role from UserDTO to the RoleEntity. I am using dozer mapper map method to map DTO to Entity.
*dozerMapper* is an object of **DozerBeanMapper**.
*userDTO* is an object of **UserDTO** 
and *userEntity* an object of **UserEntity**.

```
//In createUser(UserDTO userDTO)
  dozerMapper.map(userDTO, userEntity);
```

**Errors:**

```
MapId: null
Type: null
Source parent class: com.iiminds.crm.dto.UserDTO
Source field name: role
Source field type: class java.lang.String
Source field value: Admin
Dest parent class: com.iiminds.crm.entity.UserEntity
Dest field name: role
Dest field type: com.iiminds.crm.entity.RoleEntity

org.dozer.MappingException: Illegal object type for the method 'setRole'. 
 Expected types: 
com.iiminds.crm.entity.RoleEntity
 Actual types: 
java.lang.String

2018-10-29 16:15:39.229 ERROR 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/crm] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.dozer.MappingException: Illegal object type for the method 'setRole'. 
 Expected types: 
com.iiminds.crm.entity.RoleEntity
 Actual types: 
java.lang.String] with root cause
```

Comment: You have to pass RoleEntity to setRole and not a String

Comment: Yes Arahasya, I am totally aware of that. But from UI you can't ask for role_id too. Moreover, I want to generate the id automatically.

Comment: post code where you are using setRole

Comment: I am using Spring boot. So the values are coming from UI.

Comment: Updated the post, you can check now.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your `UserDTO.java` you have role as `String` while in `UserEntity.java` type of role is `RoleEntity`. You cannot map String to `RoleEntity`. However, in mapping file you can exclude role field from mapping like:

```
    <class-a>UserDTO</class-a>
    <class-b>UserEntity</class-b>
    <field-exclude>
        <a>role</a> 
        <b>role</b> 
    </field-exclude>
```

P.S: Fill fully qualified class name.

Then you can manually create `RoleEntity` and set it to role in `UserEntity`

Comment: Yes Sir, that is on purpose. Actually, the use case is, from UI I will be getting just the role. But while storing I need to store the role in diff table and give the ref of the role in UserEntity table. Now the problem is, the model is ready but couldn't able to map it.

Comment: Apologies, I will check and let you know. Thanks :)